# Want to merge data from two different Grids

Tags: silverlight-4.0, merge, grid, html, tab-ordering

I am working on a silverlight application and am creating girds dynamically with each having one row and two columns. In the first grid I am populating column with some fields(text box/ combobox/ datepicker etc) and leaving column 2 blank. In the second grid I am populating the second column and leaving the first blank and so on alternately. Now I want the data from the second column in the second grid in the first grid. (In a way I want to merge two grids). Is there any way to do that?

It goes something like this:

```
   <Grid>
   <views:DynamicFieldsView IsTabStop="True" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding   Path=FieldProperties}" />
    </Grid>
```

And the dynamicFieldsView is like this:

```
<Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="{Binding GridColumnNumber}" width = 140 ....>

<Controls:FieldItemControl FieldType="{Binding Type}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="{Binding FieldGridColumnNumber}">
<Controls:FieldItemControl.DataTemplates>
<Controls:TemplateSelectorDataTemplate FieldType="TextBox">  
          <TextBox Text="{Binding UserText}" width = 200 ....>
</Controls:TemplateSelectorDataTemplate>
<Controls:TemplateSelectorDataTemplate FieldType="Button">
          <Button x:Name="SearchButton" Margin="10 10 10 0" .....>
</Controls:TemplateSelectorDataTemplate>
<Controls:TemplateSelectorDataTemplate FieldType="DropDownList">
          <DynamicControls:AutoCompleteComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" Width =200 ....>
</Controls:TemplateSelectorDataTemplate>

 ....
 ....
 ....
 </Controls:FieldItemControl.DataTemplates>
 </Controls:FieldItemControl>
 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clone the control from the second grid into the first and make a binding so both display same data.

Comment: I dont think it will work for my case becuse I dont know which field will I be getting next.

Comment: How are these fields getting into the grid?